# Have the default partitions required by Windows 10 been cloned correctly (by Acronis True Image)?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, clone

Backstory:

I had a 1TB HDD (Disk 0 in image) and wanted to got an SSD (500GB). I cloned the HDD to the SSD (it respectively cloned and downgraded the partitions too). I had previously was dual booting with Ubuntu and didn't know that there was a specific process to removing Ubuntu. Anyway after a multitude of issues, the last issue I got was `Your PC/Device needs to be repaired. A required Device isn't connected or can't be accessed. Error code 0x0000225` (there was an issue with Winload.efi) running `BCDBoot c:\Windows` seemed to fix it  and I was able to boot. I then became somewhat curious about the partitions e.g if EFI has been cloned (via Acronis True Image) correctly (since I couldn't see it in diskpart until running the command just mentioned).

**How can I verify if I have all the partitions required by the Windows 10 have been cloned (they are Windows 10 associated partitions e.g windows recovery etc) and if the partitions highlighted in red contain anything -- since they seem empty to me.**

[image]
(The unallocated partition used to be the C: drive which I have now deleted).

Comment: If you can boot, then EFI has been cloned successfully. The rest doesn't seem identical. How did you do the cloning?

Comment: @harrymc https://youtu.be/pQw4E8ecL5c?t=51 I followed these instructions that were provided by my SSD manufacturer

Answer (score 0):

If you can boot, then EFI has been cloned successfully.
As you have used the well-know Acronis tool for cloning, it seemed to have
done correctly the cloning into a smaller disk.

However, Acronis being a Windows product, it probably did a bad job on the Linux
partitions, which are perhaps the ones you have encircled in red.

If you would like to verify their contents, you can always enter Disk Management,
assign them drive-letters and try to have a look at the contents.
If the contents cannot be displayed, then the partition most likely is from Linux.

However, since you still have the original disk, you don't run a big risk if you
delete them one-by-one, rebooting after each delete.
At worst, you will need to repeat the cloning process that you already did,
this time leaving alone the problematic partition.

Comment: Normally Windows 10 requires 4 partitions (check google) so I assume I have one extra partition that I dont need in disk 0. None of my partitions in Disk 0 are linux partitions as I have already deleted those by using Gparted, I cannot assign a drive letter to these partitions (not sure why). And lastly I intelligently formatted Disk 0 since it didn't like having two bootable drives and confused the bios...

Comment: This is before deleting the last partition that I didnt need (/dev/sda6/) and then expanding /dev/sda5 giving me the 918GB partition https://imgur.com/a/PwrTAoc Which also proves i dont have any linux partitions...

Comment: The disk structure is complex and not everything is visible in Disk Management. You may disconnect Disk 0 while trying to delete the unused partitions. Be sure to test that you can still enter recovery from boot. Alternatively, you may repeat the cloning with another product that may do a better job than Acronis.

Comment: "The disk structure is complex and not everything is visible in Disk Management." I know thats why I said this image from Gparted in Linux usb mode (where disk 0 isnt in use) shows that there are no linux partitions. All partitions that I dont need have been deleted (since disk 0 has 5 partitions im not sure which isnt needed) but my concern is simply have the other "recovery partitions" been cloned properly which I cannot verify.

Comment: There is only one recovery partition, and it's easy enough to test if it works. Multiple recovery partitions may be created by major Windows upgrades, but only the last one is functional.

Comment: I have edited the answer. The clone looks fine, the only issue I see is that for some reason the Windows recovery partition doesnt offer me the same options that I originally had, such as use CMD.

Comment: If you suspect the copy was faulty or that you ended up with an older recovery partition, you could try [Startup Repair](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html) and if that doesn't help [In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html). Acronis is well-known but I abandoned it after some trouble.